# SQL Server Bulk Import Column Delimiters

Tags: sql, sql-server, bulkinsert, sql-insert

I have an import file that looks like this

```
"Start Date","End Date","Name"
"2014-08-12 10:39:10","2014-08-12 10:50:09","Joe"
```

The first row is the header.

I am struggling to import using the below constraints. I am assuming that the import isn't liking the commas? Is there a way to strip them out?

```
FIELDTERMINATOR = '','',
ROWTERMINATOR = ''\n'',
FIRSTROW = 2
```

Comment: Any error messages to go with your problem? What is the exact command to launch the import, etc...

Comment: There isnt an error message; the data just doesnt import. This leads me to suspect I have an issue with my column deliminator